# Adding the same vector space to two other with same dimension.

Tags: linear-algebra

Given $V,V'$ vector sub spaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $k=\dim V=\dim V'$

> Can we find a vector subspace $W$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with dimension $n-k$ such that 
>   $$\mathbb{R}^n=W\oplus V=W\oplus V' $$
>   I mean for every pair of vector subspace with the same dimension can we find other vector sub space that serves as complement of both?

How can I construct that vector space?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose $k<n$. Put $E=\mathbb{R}^n$. Then we have $V\cup V'\not =E$. If not, $V\cup V'=E$ and $V\cup V'$ is a subspace, this imply that one of $V$ or $V'$ is included in the other, and (as they have the same dimension) they are equal, a contradiction, as hence $V\cup V'=V=E$. Now take $f_{k+1}\not \in V\cup V'$. Put $V_1=<V,f_{k+1}>$, the subspace spanned by $V$ and $f_{k+1}$, $V'_1=<V',f_{k+1}>$. If $k+1=n$, we are done with $W=<f_{k+1}>$. If $k+1<n$, repeat the above with $V_1$ and $V'_1$: we have that the dimension of $V_1$ and $V'_1$ is $k+1$, hence again $V_1\cup V'_1$ is not equal to $E$, we can find $f_{k+2}$ not in $V_1\cup V'_1$, etc,  until we reach $n$, and the subspace $W$ you want is $<f_{k+1},\cdots, f_n>$.

Comment: I think you should be a bit more explicit when it comes to choosing $f_{k+2}$.

Comment: @Michael Albanese: Thanks for your comment, I have edited my answer.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson: Thanks for the comment. I have edited again...